# Sorting objects by fixed values

Tags: javascript, sorting

Say I have a this:

["Done", "Pending", "Busy"]

How would I sort that so the order is busy, pending, done?

I will have a list of objects, each with a status value of either done, pending and busy. So there might be 100's.

Im not sure how this works, because its not alphabetical or logical, its based on user preference.

I want them to always be i that order.

Im using javascript to sort the array.

```
Checksum: "e791e37b19187712fc95078e8fd2b367"
FileLastWriteTimeUtc: "2013/06/07 01:22:40 PM"
FileName: "1.jpg"
PartsSuccess: 0
PartsTotal: 0
Path: "\Image Content Tests"
Size: 4174754
Status: "Done"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example object from your list of objects?

Comment: you need to write custom compare function and use it with conjunction with `Array.sort` func. More information on `sort` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Added a object, so Status could be Done, Busy and Pending

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign each of your values a sort order. This sort order is a number, and entirely up to you on what to make them. You then sort by the sort order of the value you actually want to sort. An example:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        state: "Pending"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        state: "Done"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        state: "Busy"
    }
];

var sortOrders = {
    "Done": 1,
    "Busy": 2,
    "Pending": 3
};

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return sortOrders[a.state] - sortOrders[b.state];
});
```

demo: http://ideone.com/qsz52d

Comment: Ah, simple. I was thinking in this direction to! Thanks, this will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list of objects is an array, use a custom sort function:

```
sortMe.sort(function (a, b) {
    var statusA = ['Busy', 'Pending', 'Done'].indexOf(a.Status),
        statusB = ['Busy', 'Pending', 'Done'].indexOf(b.Status);
    return statusA - statusB;
});
```

where `sortMe` is something like the following:

```
var sortMe = [{
    "Checksum": "e791e37b19187712fc95078e8fd2b367",
    "FileLastWriteTimeUtc": "2013/06/07 01:22:40 PM",
    "FileName": "1.jpg",
    "PartsSuccess": 0,
    "PartsTotal": 0,
    "Path": "\Image Content Tests",
    "Size": 4174754,
    "Status": "Done"
},{
    "Checksum": "e791e37b19187712fc95078e8fd2b367",
    "FileLastWriteTimeUtc": "2013/06/07 01:22:40 PM",
    "FileName": "2.jpg",
    "PartsSuccess": 0,
    "PartsTotal": 0,
    "Path": "\Image Content Tests",
    "Size": 4174754,
    "Status": "Busy"
},{
    "Checksum": "e791e37b19187712fc95078e8fd2b367",
    "FileLastWriteTimeUtc": "2013/06/07 01:22:40 PM",
    "FileName": "3.jpg",
    "PartsSuccess": 0,
    "PartsTotal": 0,
    "Path": "\Image Content Tests",
    "Size": 4174754,
    "Status": "Pending"
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have objects like

```
[
{
    'name' : 'Sending mail to manager',
    'status': 'pending'
},

{
    'name' : 'Talking to girl friend',
    'status': 'busy'
},

{
    'name' : 'Breakfast',
    'status': 'done'
},
]
```

I suggest you to use [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

```
_.sortBy(a, function(obj) {
    if (obj.status === 'busy') {
        return 1; 
    } else if (obj.status === 'pending') { 
        return 2; 
    }
    return 3; 
})
```